# using an exclude list for an rsync cronjob

Tags: cron, rsync

I have a cron job on my computer set to run on an external volume each night. I would like to add an exclude list as part of this. However, I can't figure out where to place the list in order to have it read by the rsync command. I've tried placing it in my /usr/local/bin/ which is where the script that my cron job uses is, and putting just the name of the exclude file in the script. I've also tried putting the script on the external volume and providing the entire path. I know the list itself works because I tested it with files on my desktop. I would appreciate any help! The rsync script itself works as expected, I just need to figure out this one issue.

This is the code:

```
DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)
ICE="/Volumes/ice"
RTG="/Volumes/ice/rtg/"
LOGFILE="/Users/diunt-02/Desktop/${DATE}_ICEnightmoves.log"

find "${ICE}" -type d -iname 'X*X' -exec rsync -rthvP --exclude-from= 'exclude.txt' --exclude=".*" --exclude="jpegs" --exclude="*.jpg" --log-file="${LOGFILE}" --log-file-format="${DATE} '%f' %l " --remove-source-files "{}/" "${RTG}" \;
```